# How to get the filename as string if the file is under the assets directory?

Tags: java, android, android-xml

- I have xml file under ASSETS dir (com.android.project\assets\xml\file.xml).
- I want to call a (following) function to read the xml file and return the contents as String.
- The function requires the `path` of the file as string. I don't know how to give the path of the file as string.

  ```
  private String getXML(String path){

    String xmlString = null;

    AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
    try {
      InputStream is = am.open(path);
      int length = is.available();
      byte[] data = new byte[length];
      is.read(data);
      xmlString = new String(data);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return xmlString;
  }
  ```

The file.xml:

```
    <Items>
        <ItemData>
            <ItemNumber>ABC</ItemNumber>
            <Description>Desc1</Description>        
            <Price>9.95</Price>        
            <Weight>10.00</Weight>    
        </ItemData>    
        <ItemData>        
            <ItemNumber>XYZ</ItemNumber>        
            <Description>"Desc2"</Description>        
            <Price>19.95</Price>
            <Weight>22.22</Weight>
        </ItemData>
    </Items>
```

QUESTIONS:

- How can I call the function `getXML(String path)` with a path as string parameter, if my file is located under \assets\xml\file.xml ?
- Finally, Is there any better way of reading XML file as a String?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried with strings like `/assets/xml/file.xml` and many similar strings like this using back and forward slashes.

Comment: Looks like you need to figure out what your working directory is and what the relative path to your file is.

Comment: use: file:///android_asset/xml/file.xml

Comment: Thank you njzk2, `xml/file.xml` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the path is just the path under the assets directory using forward slash (/)

so assets/x/y.z is referenced as this.getAssets().open("x/y.z");

That isnt the correct way to read the data - Inputstream.read isnt garunteed to read all the data it returns the number of bytes read - likely this will work for smaller file but you might get problems with bigger ones.

This is general code i read to to read text files, instead of a FileReader use an InputStreamReader

```
StringBuilder sw = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(file));
String readline = "";
while ((readline = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
    sw.append(readline);
}
String string = sw.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll now try this code. Do you want to say "instead of InputStreamReader user Filereader? or the last sentence just confuses me.

Comment: what is "file"? In the current scenario how do I initialize "file" with?

Comment: new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(is));

Answer (score 2):

The following would work:

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("xml/file.xml");
```

Comment: Wrong Answer! The correct way is `xml/file.xml` NOT `file.xml` according to the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: thank you saafh, for the correction. Hope u got the solution.. :)